# UFF parsing failed on line 255 in statement assert(parser.parse_buffer(stream, 0, network, model_datatype))

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorrt

I wanted to optimize my model using a library TensorRT, but i have a error `AssertionError: UFF parsing failed on line 255 in statement assert(parser.parse_buffer(stream, 0, network, model_datatype))` when i try excute function `trt.legacy.utils.uff_to_trt_engine`. I am a new in TensorRT.  Tell me, what am I doing wrong? thanks

```
FROZEN_FPATH = 'frozen.pb'
ENGINE_FPATH = 'engine.plan'
INPUT_NODE = 'the_input_kz'
ONPUT_NODE = 'softmax_kz/truediv'
INPUT_SIZE = [3,1024,1024]
MAX_BATCH_SIZE =1
MAX_WORKSPACE =1<<20

uff_model = uff.from_tensorflow_frozen_model(FROZEN_FPATH, [ONPUT_NODE])

parser =uffparser.create_uff_parser()
parser.register_input(INPUT_NODE,INPUT_SIZE,0)
parser.register_output(ONPUT_NODE)
G_LOGGER = trt.Logger(trt.Logger.INFO)

engine = trt.legacy.utils.uff_to_trt_engine(G_LOGGER, uff_model, parser, MAX_BATCH_SIZE, MAX_WORKSPACE)
```

When executing a function `trt.legacy.utils.uff_to_trt_engine` an error is issued